# JSOUP parsing returns main page and not url provided

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

I am parsing a Webpage using Jsoup.connect(URL).get()

When parsing the following page https://www.sports.com/soccer/scoreboard, it does not provide the source code of https://www.sports.com/soccer/scoreboard, but rather the source code of https://www.sports.com

It worked in the past, but seem to have changed - do you have any solution to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Are there redirects? I guess they found a way to figure out if you are a real browser or not and if not redirect you to their main page.

Comment: Remove cookies for this website in your browser and see what happens. They have added page to accept privacy policy. You have to add cookie for your request to get actual content.

Comment: Thanks - I found the cookie that is needed, but somehow it still does not work - not sure if use the cookie correctly: Jsoup.connect(url2)
      .cookie("euConsent","true")
      .get();

Comment: The above works - added it to the wrong line in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add this to the request - thanks to Luk

.cookie("euConsent","true")